# Dotnet Core 3.1 - Updating to 3.1 and setting default values using "HasDefaultValue" doesnt seem to exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Updating to Dotnet Core 3.1 and porting my code I find that in my DbContext I am getting the following error:

> 'PropertyBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'HasDefaultValue' and no accessible extension method 'HasDefaultValue'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code where this occurs follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.TenantNo).HasMaxLength(20);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.ContactLastName).HasDefaultValue(false).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Email).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.MobilePhone).HasMaxLength(20).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.OfficePhone).HasMaxLength(20);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.CompanyEmail).HasMaxLength(500);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Address1).HasMaxLength(500);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Address2).HasMaxLength(500);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.ABN).HasMaxLength(14);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.Database).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().Property(t => t.IsLocked).HasDefaultValue(false);
```

Where ever I have used .HasDefaultValue I am getting this error. I have, I believe, all the required directives...

```
using JobsLedger.CATALOG.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Seems in upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 they missed this out or they are using a different way of setting default values..

So before I posted this I did do a google search and also a Stackoverflow search with no results.

Wondering someone might suggest how to set default values in 3.1?

Comment: Don't use the `Entity Framework` tag for `Entity Framework Core` questions (it even specifically says so in the tag description).

Comment: Apologies for that.. S.

Answer (score 8):

Have you added that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/ package in your project for the 3.1 core?

I suggest that you install and/or remove/install the package and see how this works.

Nothing has changed in EF 3.1 as you can see in the changelog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-1-and-entity-framework-6-4/)

> To this end we have fixed over 150 issues for the 3.1 release, but there are no major new features to announce.

By the way, [this is the current code for 3.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions.cs) in the package, where you can see the existance of the extention.

```
    public static PropertyBuilder HasDefaultValue(
        [NotNull] this PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder,
        [CanBeNull] object value = null)
    {
        Check.NotNull(propertyBuilder, nameof(propertyBuilder));

        propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetDefaultValue(value ?? DBNull.Value);

        return propertyBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: So I simply uninstalled and then re-installed a number of the packages and now its actually recognised. Thankyou - for me that was outside the box.

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help!

Comment: what version of Entity Framecore are you currently using? I am having the same issue with 3.1.6.

Comment: @Daniel i understand the problem. Probably we are using entityframeworkcore package but we should use entityframeworkcore.relational package. I uninstall efcore and install efcore.relational and it solved.

Comment: I think you can accept this answer no?